# Making if statement with lots of conditions more simple with loop

Tags: c

I have this bit of code:

```
if(i!=j && i!=k && j!=k)
```

How can I change this into a loop instead of having to manually check if its not equal?

Comment: A loop won’t make it more simple.  There’s nothing to loop on, so if anything it would make things more convoluted.

Comment: Doesn't `i != j && i != k` => `j != k` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk nope... consider i = 3, j = 5 and k = 5.  In this case `i != j` and `i != k`, but `j == k`

Comment: Och right, it's `!=` not `==`

Comment: Do you mean "if I have *N* variables and I want to check if they're all different"? Variables are the problem here. Use an array if these are all related, it makes comparing a lot easier as you can use loops. You can't use loops with unrelated variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have N different variables in an array

```
int v[N];
```

to check that they are all different, you have to compare each pair. If any pair has equal variables, the result is false.

```
int result = 1;
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    for (size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        if (v[i] == v[j])
            result = 0;
```

If the `false` outcome is likely, you might want to do early termination:

```
int result = 1;
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++)
        if (v[i] == v[j])
        {
            result = 0;
            goto DONE;
        }
DONE:
...
```

If you organize the code as a function, you can write it without `goto`:

```
bool are_all_different(int v[], size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (v[i] == v[j])
                return false;
    return true;
}
```

---

If performance is very important for your application, you may want to store your variables in a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) or a [bit map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array).

Comment: `goto` - horrible - just make it function (even inline) and forget about `goto`

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, you're not going to get it any *simpler,* since that's about as simple as you can get. You're certainly not going to be able to do it in a loop unless you somehow get those variables into an array, or something else that can be easily processed by a loop.

What you *can* do is to clarify the intent of your statement so that it's more readable, by encapsulating the comparisons and making it less likely that you'll get one of the variables wrong.

That could be done with a simple function along the lines of:

```
int ThreeDifferent(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (a == b) return 1;
    if (a == c) return 1;
    return (b != c);
}
```

Then you simply call that function with:

```
if (ThreeDifferent(i, j, k)) ...
```

That, of course, has the disadvantage of requiring specific functions for different argument counts but, for your immediate purposes, it's certainly an option.

And I'd *only* suggest it if you *need* the added readabilty. There's probably very little wrong with your original code that a bit of added white space wouldn't fix:

```
if ((i != j) && (i != k) && (j != k))
```

Answer (score -1):

It may have sense if you have large number of values to be compare to another value or values (for example from sensors). Some example functions

```
int AND_EQUAL(int *ValuesToComape, size_t size, int value)
{
    int result = 1;
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size && result; index++)
    {
        result = result && (ValuesToComape[index] == value);
    }
    return result;
}



int OR_EQUAL(int *ValuesToComape, size_t size, int value)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size && !result; index++)
    {
        result = result || (ValuesToComape[index] == value);
    }
    return result;
}

int AND_GT(int *ValuesToComape, size_t size, int *values)
{
    int result = 1;
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size && result; index++)
    {
        result = result && (ValuesToComape[index] > values[index]);
    }
    return result;
}



int OR_GT(int *ValuesToComape, size_t size, int *values)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size && !result; index++)
    {
        result = result || (ValuesToComape[index] > values[index]);
    }
    return result;
}
```